# Setting radio button with Casperjs

Tags: radio-button, casperjs

I'm trying without success to set the value of a radio button with CasperJS.

Can somebody explain to me why the assertEval is failing on this test?

```
    this.test.assertExist('input[name=main][value=yes]');

    casper.thenEvaluate(function(term) {
        document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').setAttribute('checked', true);
    });

    this.test.assertEval(function() {
        return document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').getAttribute('checked') == "true";
    }, 'Main was set to true');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why this assert is failing, we need to understand that each call to `casper.then` defines a new navigation step, and `casper.run` executes each step in the order that they're defined.  So the code within your `casper.then` block is an async callback.

If you annotate your code like this:

```
    this.test.assertExists('input[name=main][value=yes]');

    casper.then(function() {
        this.echo('Select the radio button');
        this.evaluate(function() {
            document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').setAttribute('checked', true);
        }
    });

    this.echo('Assert that the radio button is selected');
    this.test.assertEval(function() {
        return document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').getAttribute('checked') == "true";
    }, 'Main was set to true');
```

You will notice that "Assert that the radio button is selected" gets printed before "Select the radio button".  So there's your problem!

### The Solution:

You may not need to use `then` if you're not performing any navigation steps.  In that case, you can simply use `evaluate` instead of `thenEvaluate`.  Or if you really need to use `then`, just put `assertEval` into the same `casper.then` block:

```
    this.test.assertExists('input[name=main][value=yes]');

    casper.then(function() {
        this.evaluate(function(term) {
            document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').setAttribute('checked', true);
        });
        this.test.assertEval(function() {
            return document.querySelector('input[name=main][value=yes]').getAttribute('checked') == "true";
        }, 'Main was set to true');
    });
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. There was also a response with a simpler solution on the CasperJS groups: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/casperjs/E0MKI4Eqdg8/MdNffIXLcc4J

Comment: Cool, I didn't even think to use casper.click that way!

Comment: This isn't good enough- some people's use cases don't have the option to use the @value parameter.