# Does thenEvaluate() return in the same way as evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

So I know I can return data to casper from the `window` using return...

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
    return 'foobar';
}, {});
```

How do I achieve the same thing with `thenEvaluate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return anything from `casper.thenEvaluate`. It will be disregarded. You need to split it into `casper.then` with `casper.evaluate`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967945/setting-radio-button-with-casperjs) for something similar.

`casper.thenEvaluate` is an asynchronous step function just like all other `then*` and `wait*` functions. Returning something useful from an asynchronous function is not possible. What you most likely want is this:

```
var something;
casper.start(url).then(function(){
    something = this.evaluate(function(){
        return 'foobar';
    });
    this.click("someSelector");
}).then(function(){
    // do something with "something" on the new page
});
```

I suspect you wouldn't be asking if you didn't want to use `something` later. All step functions return the initial `casper` object so that scripts can be written in promise syntax as in the above example.